# How to check If Windows game mode is currently active?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-11, gaming

Is there a method to detect if Windows Game Mode is currently active (i.e. the user is playing a game — not is game mode enabled)?

I've searched the web a fair bit but only managed to find a few tidbits of info useful if you're developing a C++ application.

Ideally, I could check using PowerShell, Command Prompt, WSL, or anything preinstalled on most PCs.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no direct technical correlation between Windows Game Mode and the user actually playing a game. Personally. I use Game Mode to do screen capture etc.. Also you can play (any?) game without invoicing Game Mode. It would help if you were more specific. Also there are a lot of variables, can the user install software, are there any games installed, can the user go on any website etc. Essentially even regular Email would allow to play a game (e.g. sending back and forth chess moves), you really need to be more specific and define the scope - what do you consider a game?

Comment: @Albin "Game Mode" is different from "Game Bar" and related features. Game mode used to prioritize CPU for certain processes, but that function and the API apps used to work with it no longer exist (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/expandedresources/nf-expandedresources-hasexpandedresources). I believe it still disables certain notifications and windows updates though, but there isn't any way to tell when it's active anymore as far as I'm aware

Comment: @Stebs_tc can you describe what you want to do with this information? There are ways to check whether a full-screen application is running for example

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thanks for the clarification, currently I'm not sure the user know what exactly he is asking  `i.e. the user is playing a game — not is game mode enabled`. Seems detecting "Game Mode" is not his actual goal but to check if gaming at all is going on?!

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Not sure if you did the downvote on my answer, but it would be nice if you would elaborate (you can leave the downvote of course).

Answer (score 0):

Detecting a running Steam game can be done via the registry.
In registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam` check
the item `RunningAppID`. If the item exists and its value is
not zero, then a Steam game is currently running.

Other checks exist that fit better the Stack Overflow site:

- Use if [IDirect3DDevice9::TestCooperativeLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9helper/nf-d3d9helper-idirect3ddevice9-testcooperativelevel)
  returns `DDERR_EXCLUSIVEMODEALREADYSET`. See this
  [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/557345/determining-whether-game-mode-is-active).
- Use the `SHQueryUserNotificationState` function to determine
  whether the user is playing a full screen D3D game.
  It will report QUNS_RUNNING_D3D_FULL_SCREEN.
  ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724599/how-to-know-if-computer-is-in-gaming-mode))

Answer (score -1):

**What is your primary question (please reduce your post to a single question)?!**

From your specification:

> (i.e. the user is playing a game — not is game mode enabled)

I assume it is primarily `"is the user is playing a game?"` - despite the needed specification  (see my comment) - I would suggest to setup a PC to your specs (without games) and remove the right to install or execute any new software.

you need to restrict website access as well, e.g. by allowing only certain sites (easy but this might not meet your requirements) or disallowing games websites (more tedious to administer, you might wanna use a commercial firewall/webblocker list for that purpose).

This will take care of the two most obvious game resources. However, keep in mind that almost anything can be used to play a game. Depending on your target group the better solution might be to educate your users on why they shouldn't play games.